# WPF VB.net sharing public sub procedures

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, public-method

I'm new to VB.net so please understand. I have a `MainWindow, Frame1, Frame2 (AdFrame1), Page1.`

`MainWindow` loads `Page1` from `Frame1` on startup. In `MainWindow.vb class` I have a Public Sub that makes `Frame2` visible.

How would I share that Public Sub so I could use Page_Mouseup Event to show Frame2 (AdFrame1)

I tried Public Shared Sub, but I get this error: "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class"

Code in MainWindow.vb:

```
Private Sub MainWindow2_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp


        AdClick()

    End Sub



    Public Sub AdClick()



        Try


            clicks += 1

            If clicks >= 10 Then

                'After 5 seconds Adframe CloseLink and TextBlock1 will hide.
                AdFrame1.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
                CloseMainButton.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
                InitializeComponent()
                dpTimer = New DispatcherTimer
                dpTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000)
                AddHandler dpTimer.Tick, AddressOf TickMe
                dpTimer.Start()

                clicks = 0

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Oops! Error X0123A1. Please contact us with error ASAP!", "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK)
        End Try
    End Sub


    'After 10 sesonds auto close
    Private Sub TickMe()

        AdFrame1.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden

    End Sub
```

Code Page1.vb

```
  Private Sub Page1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp


            AdClick() (inaccessible due to protection)

        End Sub
```

So how would share AdClick() with Page1

Comment: Frame2 MUST be shown on MainWindow.

Comment: Why not go along the paths of the error message and remove the "Shared" from your Sub?

Comment: Please re-read. I edited my original post to clear things up. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that the `Shared` keyword is not related to *visibility* - members can be `Public Shared` or `Private Shared`, for example.  A `Shared` member is the same as a `static` member in C# - it is common to all instances of a class (see : [What is the use of a shared variable in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613998/what-is-the-use-of-shared-variable-in-vb-net))

For the actual question, I'd suggest just hooking up the event that is already there :

```
Class MainWindow2
    Private WithEvents _Page1 as New Page1

    Private Sub MainWindow2_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) _
                                            Handles Me.MouseUp, _Page1.MouseUp 
        AdClick()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AdClick()
         'Do something
    End Sub
End Class
```

Exposing methods is usually the wrong approach - if you want `MainWindow` to do something it is far better that it remains responsible for doing it itself, not having some other class trying to do it elsewhere.  With events, `Page1` is only responsible for letting `MainWindow` know that it has been clicked; this leaves it up to `MainWindow` to decide what to do about it and `Page1` needs know nothing about the methods that are contained in `MainWindow`.

You can even add custom events - if you had a button on `Page1`, for example :

```
Class Page1
    'make your own event
    Public Event Button1Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) _
                                                         Handles Button1.Click
        RaiseEvent Button1Click(sender, e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

and then in `MainWindow` :

```
Private Sub ClickHandle(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) _
                                                   Handles _Page1.Button1Click
    AdClick()
End Sub
```

This would let a button click inside the page be propagated up to the main window.

If your pages are created at runtime you cannot use `WithEvents` and `Handles` but you can do :

```
Dim newPage as New Page1
AddHandler newPage.MouseUp, AddressOf MainWindow2_MouseUp
```

Just make sure to remove the handler before the page goes out of scope when you are finished with it (Handlers keep a strong reference so `newPage` will never get garbage collected with a handler still attached! --> memory leak).

```
RemoveHandler newPage.MouseUp, AddressOf MainWindow2_MouseUp
```

Comment: So I should be able use the MouseUp event(above code)  without out stating the Method (AdClick) in Page 1, right.

Comment: @BenjaminJones - yes, I've added a bit more code to maybe clear up the context.