# Hot to use more socket?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

I have a form called frmmsg.
I get the following warning when I open a new frmmsg :

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
>   is normally permitted.

How can I open the form using more socket?

This is the code that I'm using:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Public Class frmmsg
    Dim listener As New TcpListener(8000)
    Dim client As TcpClient
    Dim message As String

    Private Sub frmmsg_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim thread As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listening))
        listener.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub listening()
        listener.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnnewform_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnnewform.Click
        Dim fnew As New frmmsg
        fnew.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As apparent from the message you can only open one listening socket per port (in general).

Therefore, you must ensure that there is only one instance of `TcpListener(8000)` at the same time. If you want to have multiple forms open at the same time you need to reference this object not from the form instances. Maybe use a static/shared variable.

Comment: can you give me example? :D, Thank you for your comment

Comment: Any concrete problems?

Comment: I just do not understand how to use static/shared variable and not from the form instances.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613998/what-is-the-use-of-shared-variable-in-vb-net This should help. Shared variables have one value globally while instance variables have one value per instance. You want one global TCP socket variable.