# Object reference not set to an instance of an object at execution

Tags: vb.net

```
Function MD5Hash(ByVal values As String) As Byte()
    Return MD5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(values))
End Function

Function Encrypt(ByVal Stringinput As String, ByVal key As String) As String
    des.Key = MD5Hash(key)
    des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    Dim buffer As Byte() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Stringinput)
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(des.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
End Function


Private Sub btnSignup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSignup.Click
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString.ToString)

    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO LoginTB (user, password) VALUES (@username,@password)"
    con.Open()
        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(query, con)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TxtBxUsername.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Encrypt(TxtBxPassword.Text, "abc"))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("user created successfully")
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

The error appears in the value at MD5Hash when I click the signup button.

> System.NullReferenceException 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I know it has been asked a lot. But I couldn't find a solution to this issue.

Comment: Declare `Encrypt` and `MD5Hash` as [`Shared`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/613998/1115360) methods, i.e. `Shared Function MD5Hash(ByVal values As String) As Byte()` etc.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the code line producing the error and inspect the variables to see which one is `Nothing`. Initialize this variable.

Comment: when i declare it as share, it shows me `Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may caused due to instance is not created for MD5. Can you try change your code for the function `MD5Hash` as below?

```
Function MD5Hash(ByVal values As String) As Byte()
    Static hash As MD5 = MD5.Create()
    Return hash.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(values))
End Function
```

Comment: Local variable cannot have the same name as the function containing it. GETTING THIS ERROR

Comment: **Inside the function**, change `md5Hash` to something else, like just `hash`, **in both places**, leaving the function name the same.  I'd also change `Dim` to `Static` so the function reuses the same instance each time.